# Add text to '.foo' if parent container also contains '.foo2'

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to add 'Hello World' to .foo, but only if the container (product) also contains .foo2. I've got half way with the following code, however it adds the appended text to all instances of .foo, not just the specify product containers that also have .foo2.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Add text to foo if product contains foo2</title>
<style>
.product {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px #333 solid;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    if($('.product > .foo2').length > 0){
        $(".foo").append("Hello World");
    }
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Div 1 -->
<div class="product">
1
<div class="foo"></div>
</div>

<!-- Div 2 -->
<div class="product">
2
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo2"></div>
</div>

<!-- Div 3 -->
<div class="product">
3
<div class="foo"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to operate on each `.product` individually with `.each()`:

```
$(".product").each(function() {
    var $foo = $(this).children(".foo");

    // using $something.length as a test to determine if it exists
    if ($foo.length && $(this).children(".foo2").length) {
        // so if this product has a .foo and it also has a .foo2,
        // append some text to the .foo
        $foo.append("Hello World");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
​$(function(){
    $('.product:has("div.foo2")').find('.foo').append('Hello World');
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5NSzU/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to target with a selector:

```
$(".product:has(.foo2) > .foo").append("Hello World");
```

This won't work if you need to reject products which have foo2 as an indirect child, in which case you can use a filter:

```
$(".product > .foo")
  .filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent().children(".foo2").length != 0
  }).append("Hello World");
```

Filter is a function that gets run on each element. If it returns true, the element is kept. If it returns false, the element is removed.

Answer (score 0):

here the code [jsfiddle.net/X8uUH/](http://jsfiddle.net/X8uUH/) only add 'hello world' to the second div just like you want

```
$(function() {
if($('.product > .foo2').length > 0){
  $(".product:has(.foo2) > .foo").append("Hello World");}});​
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straighforward way to do it that's similar to what you had originally

```
if($('.product').find(':contains(.foo2)')){
  $(".foo2"). siblings(".foo").append("Hello World");
}
```

​
here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ys3s/)